# Scrape image with no extension

Tags: web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape images this site:
http://mis.historiska.se/mis/sok/bild.asp?uid=336358&g=1

The site also have the option to download different sizes, like big image here:
http://catview.historiska.se/catview/media/highres/336358

I have no problem downloading manual, scraping the image, or even scraping the url, but the image and url is missing the image extension.

**I need to scrape the full url with filename and extension.**, NOT the actual image.

Answer (score 1):

The *proper* way to do this would be to check the headers after making a request to the given url for the filename and extension. A simple curl request to the given url gives me the following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Length: 569050
Date: Wed, 20 Jan 2016 15:33:49 GMT
```

The best way to guess the file extension would be to just check "Content-Type" header. Similarly, in order to get the filename, we'd be using the "Content-Disposition" header which **need not necessarily be provided** in the headers in which case we'll need to guess the filename from the URL.
A simple python snippet for guessing extension would be as follows:

```
import requests
import mimetypes
resp = requests.get(url)
content_type = resp.headers['content-type']
ext = mimetypes.guess_extension(content_type)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.
But unfortuneatly im no coder and have no idea what you are talking about, curl, headers, Phyton etc. But thats not your fault. I should have mentioned that.

So thanks for trying to help. I guess im in over my head with this website and must dump the idea of scraping it. 

If there is others with an easyer explaination that "normal" humans can understand, please let me know :)

Comment: @AndersRoss Since you mentioned that you were **scraping** the website, I automatically assumed that you might be using some or the other kind of code/snippet to do the work for you. Seems like a bad assumption.

Comment: Yes, im using cloudscrape. Its point and click interface.
Thats all my brain can handle :)
I can scape the picture with no problem, but that is not what i need. I just need the full url to the image, witch does not seem to be possible.
Thanks for your effort though.